# How to use the Out-of-Stock threshold option?

Tags: magento2, stock, out-of-stock

I see that I have the **Out-of-Stock threshold** in my admin panel, how could I use it in order to have more items in my products in stock then I really have?

[image: Magento 2 Out-of-Stock threshold]

And how does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative amount in order to have more **salable items** than you really have in stock.

### Out-of-Stock threshold

Use a negative value for this threshold to set the maximum amount of products that can be backordered before the product is truly considered out of stock. This amount adds to the salable quantity. The value set at the product level overrides any value set at the global level.

The formula for the Salable Quantity is (Quantity - (Out-of-Stock Threshold)).

The following is an example:

Quantity: 25
Notify for Quantity Below: 10
Only X left Threshold: 5
Out of Stock Threshold: -50

The Salable Quantity for this product is 75 (25 - (-50)).

[image: Magento 2 The Salable Quantity]
Example Salable Quantity before backorders enabled

[image: Magento 2 The Salable Quantity]
Example Salable Quantity after backorders enabled

When customers purchase more than 25 products, new orders enter as backorders. As the product’s Salable Quantity reduces to 5 (70 items have been sold), the Product page will display a message Only 5 left on the storefront. When the Salable Quantity reaches 0, the product is displayed as Out of Stock in the storefront.

Reference: [Magento 2 DevDocs - Out-of-Stock threshold](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html#out-of-stock-threshold)

Comment: any idea on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323458/how-to-display-custom-option-based-on-attribute